# Assign Empty Array to JSON object insted of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I'm currently adapting a python-based GUI to a javascript based web GUI. The program sends large JSON messages to some server for processing. The server recieves messages in which some values are set like so:

```
"someVar": []
```

However, I don't know how to send this in the same way from my own GUI in javascript. My solutions result in this:

```
"someVar": null
```

The server doesn't like this, but I cannot find a way to assign an empty array without it defaulting to null.

The object starts out like so:

```
{
  var1: null
  var2: "someString"
  var3: 1.3
  ...
}
```

when the server gets this, it normally prints out

```
{
  var1: []
  var2: "someString"
  var3: 1.3
  ...
}
```

so lets say this object is stored in a variable called curConfig

I want to do something like this:

```
curConfig['var1'] = []
```

But that still leaves me with a null value instead of [] when it gets sent to the server.

Comment: Why can't you just use `[]` as the initial value of the array, and then push new elements into it?

Comment: Post your code so we can see how you're initializing the object and explain how to fix it.

Comment: Why is the server printing the object twice? It sounds like the server is replacing an empty array with `null` for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a large number of `null` values that you want to change to empty array when using [JSON#stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), you can use a replace function (2nd param):

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

The function receives the key and the value, and you can decide, which value you want to return.

```js
var data = {
  var1: null,
  var2: "someString",
  var3: 1.3
};

var reslut = JSON.stringify(data, function(key, value) {
  if (value === null) {
    return [];
  }
  return value;
});

console.log(reslut);
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialize an empty array in javascript simply write it like

```
var arr = [];
```

Example for JSON

```
var obj = {
  arr: []
};
JSON.stringify(obj); // "{ "arr": [] }"
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the object like this:

```
{
  var1: [],
  var2: "someString",
  var3: 1.3,
  ...
}
```

Also,

```
curConfig.var1 = [];
```

should work, I don't know why it isn't working for you.